# In quarto, is it possible to cross reference a figure in another document?

Tags: python, r, markdown, quarto

I am writing an article in one quarto `.qmd` document and would like to refer to a figure that is in an annex in another `.qmd` document.

Reproducible example:

- article.qmd

```
See Figure @fig-a in the annex for details.
```

- annex.qmd

```
![Caption for the figure](path/to/figure.png){#fig-a}
```

Related links:

- https://quarto.org/docs/authoring/cross-references.html
- https://quarto.org/docs/books/book-crossrefs.html
- https://forums.fast.ai/t/cross-references-between-multiple-notebooks-using-nbdev-and-quarto/98473

Comment: what is your final product, or to put differently, how to you combine the two qmd's?

Comment: I keep them in 2 separate word documents (article and annex) for my colleagues for commenting, then later I'll submit to a journal (either word or latex version).

Comment: I would put {{< include _annex.qmd >}} at the end of article.qmd, then it should find that crossref.

Comment: Related question, would it be possible to do this without including the actual annex in the rendered document?

Comment: you mean two standalone pdfs? I do not think that will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For crossreferecing we have to combine the two documents, i.e. add `{{< include _annex.qmd >}}` in article.qmd. See [here](https://quarto.org/docs/authoring/includes.html) for more information on include.